# Do I need a client side framework? (web app)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, reactjs

I'm working on an application for a school project. It's supposed to be similar to:  [this site](http://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/), but hopefully my team can do a better job. I look at angular 2 and can't help but think the size and scope of the framework overshadows that of my application. And when I look towards react/redux... well I'm just not sure my team will be able to handle the tooling or non-MVC approach. However, my Googl-fu has been not so great in determining if I truly need these frameworks.

Is it possible or desirable for a team new to web development to attempt an application without the support of a framework? Are there libraries that allow for client side templating or routing? In your opinion is this worth the trouble or should I just stick to a framework?

Comment: Please comment why you downvoted, so I can improve my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself this question: will you need to maintain the code into the future?

If the answer is yes, a framework will make that infinitely easier. Yes, it will add potentially a lot of extra boilerplate, but it also means that anyone familiar with that framework should be able to trivially search, understand, and modify the code. This is because the framework will force you to do things a certain way (especially a framework such as Angular). This is also especially useful when you need to put together code from multiple developers: if they all use the same framework the code should be compatible without any real effort.

If this is a one-off project and you just want to get it done, you don't need a framework (technically you never do, save for my point above).

Comment: Thanks for the advice.